# Power BI Bigquery - Queries Issue

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Big Query and trying to visualize data using Power BI (and its connectivity to Big Query)

Yet, i understand that on Power BI I can address a table on Big Query, but if i need any manipulation on the data - it is nearly impossible to do so with Power BI syntax.

So it actually "brings me back to the table" and forcing me to create mini-tables/queries to address to in Big Query, and I'm having a hard time addressing Big Query from Power BI.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: I don't know much about Power BI, but what if you organize all your pre visualisation data manipulation in views, would that be _cleaner_ from your perspective?

Comment: it's an option, but first i want to understand if i can create it from power bi, if i want to create views how should I do that - using another system, I'll guess?

Comment: Although I didn't use it much, I found Power BI tricky to use with BigQuery too.

To create a view you can use the BigQuery UI. Just write the query that brings back the data in the format you need. Then instead of saving it as a query, use "save view".

This will save it in the same area as the datasets but you'll notice the icon is different. If you then query this view it will run your saved query as bring the data back in the right format.

[link]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Power BI for Big Query analysis. As of Q1 2019 Power BI still do not support project billing unless manually editing the connexion script, it does not support Sheets federated tables, do not support nested and repeated fields and as you said DML is nearly unusable. Microsoft do not seems to be willing to develop the compatibility between Power BI and Big Query further.

Learn more in this article (i am the author): https://medium.com/@remy_david/which-bi-tool-for-big-query-d9eb838ff7ad